# Detach and reattach a complete Screen session with multiple windows

Tags: gnu-screen

I am writing a client/server-application and when I'm testing the code I want to be able to have both the server and client in a separate terminal (+ vim). For this I thought I could use GNU Screen and divide the terminal in multiple windows (and it works great!). But I have a problem when I want to detach the whole session with windows and all. When I try to reattach the session I don't get them in windows like I arranged it, but instead they attaches like "normal" screen instances.

Also, is there a way to change the size of a screen window? Like change the height proportions of two windows splitted vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your first question isn't possible because the regions (the way the windows are displayed) are bound to a single screen instance and not to a screen session.

```
C-a : 
  resize
```

see man screen for more explanation of the resize command